Error exportando un jupyter notebook en VSCode a HTML
Estoy intentando convertir un Jupyter Notebook a HTMl desde el botón de exportar que hay en VSCode pero me da un error, hasta el otro día me funcionaba
10:07:19.816 [error] Export failed [Error: Unable to export notebook as the built-in vscode.ipynb extension is currently unavailable.
    at mb.getContent (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.6.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:321:6201)
    at yf.executeCommand (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.6.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:321:8867)
    at async OT.export (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.6.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:322:505)
    at async vb.performNbConvertExport (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.6.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:324:2500)
    at async vb.performExport (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.6.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:324:2190)
    at async vb.exportImpl (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.6.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:324:1798)
    at async vb.export (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.6.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:324:1530)
    at async a0.export (c:\Users\~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.6.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:373:3134)
    at async f.h (c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:154:204392)]

No se que extensión es la que menciona y cómo buscarla, hasta hace unas dos o 3 semanas pude exportar a un HTML sin ningún problema
